# LibGDX collision detection on moving and rotating object (rectangle enemy)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision

i am trying to get collision dectection working properly but when i do it, the collision area keeps moving. no matter what i tried.
there are 2 objects and the objects are moving and i cannot get the area of the collision to follow the enemy/object.

i am using the method below to see if the collision will work and it does not follow the enemy properly.

```
enemy class extends sprite {
```

the above is an example of how i am using the sprite extension.

the object/enemy is a sprite from libgdx the class is extended by sprite.

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);

shapeRenderer.rect(rect1.getX() + (rect1.getWidth() / 2), rect1.getY()  + (rect1.getHeight() / 2) - 2, rect1.getOriginX() - 1, rect1.getOriginY() - 4, 1.0f, 1.0f, rect1.getRotation());

shapeRenderer.rect(rect2.getX() - 10, rect2.getY() - 10, rect2.getWidth() - 10, rect2.getHeight() - 10, rect2.getOriginX(), rect2.getOriginY(), rect2.getRotation());

shapeRenderer.end();
```

this is in the enemy class collision check

```
rect.set(getX() + (getWidth() / 2), getY()  + (getHeight() / 2) - 2, getOriginX() - 1, getOriginY() - 4);
```

this is to see if the enemy is colliding

```
public boolean collides(Ball ball) {
  if (getX() < ball.getX()) {
     return (Intersector.overlaps(ball.getRect1(), rect));
  }
  return false;
```

}

Any help will be really nice.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your code to see your problem but to be able to check if two rectangles collide you can use Intersector class.

```
  if(Intersector.overlaps(rectangle1, rectangle2) {
      // Do here whatever you want.
}
```

Intersector can work with circles and polygons as well. I usually put this into the act method which I override from Actor class. If you are not using a Stage I guess you can check this in the render method.

Comment: Hi @johnny-b. If the two rectangles are correct when they overlap Intersector will return true. If you do not get true check if your rectangles are correct.  You can render with ShapeRenderer ball.getRect1() and rect in your case and check if the rectangles are correct. I can see that you are offsetting the rectangles but this depends what are you trying to achieve in your game logic.

Comment: the bullet is a like the shape of a bullet with the front rounded of so i am trying to make a rectangle inside it to be the collision detection area and not the whole sprite as that will cover the entire rectangle. this is so the area covers enough so the bullet is coverred and i am trying to implement a touch() method to kill it, so it gets taken out if you touch the rectangle area. if that is any clearer????